# levenshtein_distance in ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote `levenshtein_distance` as below to calculate the distance between two strings:

```
    def min3(a, b, c)
      if a < b && a < c then
        a
      elsif b < c then
        b
      else
        c
      end
    end

    def levenshtein_distance(s, t)
      m = s.length
      n = t.length
      return m if n.zero?
      return n if m.zero?

      d = (0..m+1).to_a
      x = nil

      s.each_char.each_with_index do |ch1, i|
        e = i + 1
        t.each_char.each_with_index do |ch2, j|
          cost = ch1 == ch2 ? 0 : 1
          x = min3(d[j + 1] + 1, e + 1, d[j] + cost)
          d[j] = e
          e = x
        end
        d[m] = x
      end
      x
    end
```

When the two strings are different, it gives an error message:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

The error detects line:

```
x = min3(d[j + 1] + 1, e + 1, d[j] + cost)
```

I thought this was due to index surpassing the defined `d`'s limit. But enlarging the length of `d` doesn't solve this problem.

Is there something I missed in implementing the algorithm?

this is the case that I tested on `irb`

```
irb(main):052:0> levenshtein_distance("a", "abc")
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):24:in `block (2 levels) in levenshtein_distance'
    from (irb):22:in `each_char'
    from (irb):22:in `each_with_index'
    from (irb):22:in `block in levenshtein_distance'
    from (irb):20:in `each_char'
    from (irb):20:in `each_with_index'
    from (irb):20:in `levenshtein_distance'
    from (irb):52
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe check these for reference? https://github.com/gstragand/Levenshtein
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Ruby

Comment: Also I ran your code and got no errors.  Can you post your test case to reproduce?

Comment: I posted test-case @lacostenycoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten the algorithm in accordance to Wikipedia:

```
def ld(s, t)
  v0 = (0..t.length).to_a
  v1 = []
  #p v0

  s.chars.each_with_index do |s_ch, i|                                                                                            
    v1[0] = i + 1                                                                                                                 

    t.chars.each_with_index do |t_ch, j|                                                                                          
      cost = s_ch == t_ch ? 0 : 1                                                                                                 
      v1[j + 1] = [v1[j] + 1, v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost].min                                                                    
    end                                                                                                                           
    v0 = v1.dup                                                                                                                   
    #p v1                                                                                                                          
  end                                                                                                                             

  v0[t.length]
end
```

It seem to work. Also you can as well uncomment `p v1` and `p v0` to see how the vectors change on each iteration.